# Конфликт пакетов: insserv: Starting nifi depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!

Tags: ubuntu, package

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь установить пакеты, мне выпадает ошибка:

```
.....
insserv: Starting nifi depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service nifi and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting nifi depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Как можно ее разрешить?

Спасибо.

Файл /etc/init.d/nifi :

```
#!/bin/sh

#
#    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
#    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
#    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
#    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
#    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
#    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#    limitations under the License.
#
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Apache NiFi is a dataflow system based on the principles of Flow-Based Programming.
#

# Make use of the configured NIFI_HOME directory and pass service requests to the nifi.sh executable
NIFI_HOME=/home/pc/Nifi/nifi-1.3.0
bin_dir=${NIFI_HOME}/bin
nifi_executable=${bin_dir}/nifi.sh

${nifi_executable} "$@"
```

Comment: `apt-get install -f` пробовал?

Comment: Да, то же самое

Comment: посмотрите на `/etc/init.d/nifi` или `/etc/rc*/*nifi` что не повреждён и синтаксис правильный в `### BEGIN INIT INFO` комментариях.  [insserv: There is a loop between service foo and bar if started... Breaks aptitude](https://serverfault.com/q/196754/3933).

Comment: Прикрепил весь текст этого файла в описании темы

Comment: @ks_on_v: Попробуйте  Provides, Required-Start, etc определить явно (если значение по умолчанию вызывает проблему). Используйте \@ник синтаксис, если хотите, чтобы оповещение о вашем комментарии пришло.